# Action bar inflateException

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I can not make an Action Bar in my app. It crashes on startup. I have tested several code examples from the internet. I have made a completely new project in Eclipse with the only purpose of adding an action bar. But I can't.

Here is my code

---

```
package com.example.testmenu;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
    {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();    
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);    
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">    
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_save"          
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_one"          
        android:title="@string/menu_one"          
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom|withText" />
</menu>
```

---

java.lang.RuntimeException: 
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testmenu/com.example.testmenu.MainActivity}: 
android.view.InflateException: 
Binary XML file line #2: 
Error inflating class menu

---

```
<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="8"
android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

---

Without the menu-tag the app runs ok.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your `Menu` should be from actionbarsherlock package. Try like this:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
    //...
```

or you can add `import`:

```
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
```